# how to make background or how to arrange a sprite backwards

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just want to make a background but when I tried to pull a background photo in, it's in front of all the other sprites, so how can you make it go backwards.

Comment: adjusting the render queue might be what you're looking for? http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-renderQueue.html

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways for that. The easiest would be just to change the z-order of the background to a value greater than your other sprites. For instance when you have a character and a background you would use 1 for the backgrounds z-order and 0 for the characters z-order.

So just click on your background sprite and in the inspector type 1 for the z-poition. Same for your character or whatever sprite you have, but this time make sure its 0 in the z-position.

The better approach is ofcourse to use layers. When you click on a sprite you will see a sprite component in the inspector attached to it by Unity automatically. In this component there is a "Order in Layer" property".
Now if you change the backgrounds order in layer property to -1 and all your other sprites have a greater value for example 0,1,2.... then the background will be pushed to back as this is its order in that particular layer.

You can also use the sorting layer property and add your own layers. Its probably the best method, but the 2 above should get you achieve what you want.